# Python pandas question matching rows, finding indexes and creating column

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning Python and trying to solve a problem but got stuck here. I would like to do the following:

The dataframe is called: `df_cleaned_sessions`

It contains two columns with timestamps:

1. `datetime_only_first_engagement`
2. `datetime_sessions`

For you information the `datetime_only_first_engagement` column has a lot less timestamps than the `datetime_sessions`, the sessions column has a lot of NA values as this dataframe is a result of a left join.

I would like to do the following:
Find rows where `datetime_only_first_engagement` timestamp equals the timestamp from `datetime_sessions`, save the index from those rows, and create a new column in the dataframe called '`is_conversion`', and set those (matching timestamps) indexes to `True`. The other indexes should be set to `False`.

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add some sample data. It's easier for us to help you that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would have been easier if you had provided a sample code and an expected output, however by reading your question I feel you would want to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Lets build a sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],[10,11]], columns=["A", "B"])
print(df)
    A   B
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
3   7   8
4   10  11
```

Lets assume df1 to be :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],[9,10]], columns=["D", "E"])
print(df1)
    D   E
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
3   7   8
4   9   10
```

Apply the below code to check if column `A` in `df` exists in Column `D` of `df1`:

```
df['is_conversion']= df['A'].isin(df1['D']).astype(bool)
print(df)


A   B   is_conversion
0   1   2   True
1   3   4   True
2   5   6   True
3   7   8   True
4   10  11  False
```

Similarly for your question, you can apply the same logic in matching different columns of the same dataframe too. I think you need:

```
df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'] = df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_only_first_engagement'].isin(df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_sessions']).astype(bool)
```

Based on the comments: add this below the above code:

```
df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'] = df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'].replace({True:1, False:0})
```

Alternative answer using `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'] = np.where(df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_only_first_engagement'].isin(df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_sessions']),True,False)
```

Hope that helps..!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it so elaborative! Works like a charm. I am experiencing many roads lead to Rome when working with Python/Pandas. Once follow-up question: if I would like the output to be 1 (int) for True and 0 (int) for False. Is there a way I can achieve this too? Thanks!

Comment: you mean `df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'] = df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'].replace({True:1, False:0})` ..??

Comment: If you think My answer was helpful , dont forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: Not a problem. All the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'] = np.where(df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_only_first_engagement'] == df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_sessions'], True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_cleaned_sessions['is_conversion'] = df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_only_first_engagement'] == df_cleaned_sessions['datetime_sessions']
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a beginner here. Follow-up question: this would result in all matching values in the 'is_conversion' column to be set to 'True', correct? How do I set the remaining values to False?

Comment: It automatically sets all the remaining values to False so no need to set this manually.